# rails Relationship Query with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

chat (id, status, name)
chat_participations (id, status, user_id)

What I want to do if get a count for how many of the user's chat_participations are status = 'unread'

So I have this:

```
  @chats_unread = current_user.chat_participations.where(:status => 'unread').count
```

That works ok but it breaks when there is a chat.status = 'closed'

I only want the count for chat's that are chat.status = ' open

I tried:

```
  @chats_unread = current_user.chat.where(:status => 'open).chat_participations.where(:status => 'unread').count
```

but that error'd. Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: From the little code here, it looks like user doesn't have a relationship with chat, so there for your current_user.chat call will not work. Also, do you have an association between chat and chat_participations?

Comment: Should chat_participations have chat_id too?

Comment: Is the exact code that you are using? Because I can seen a missing character('), the code should be
@chats_unread = current_user.chat.where(:status => 'open').chat_participations.where(:status => 'unread').count

check if it is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the table name in the conditions.

```
where('chats.status' => 'open')
where('chat_participations.status' => 'unread')
```